# Find elements in array those have come two times in array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

```
Given A = [3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 1 2 3 4 5 6 8]       
Output B = [3 4 5 6 8]
```

Is there a Matlab function or command to get this result? I am new to Matlab. Just now I am doing it going through for each element and keeping a counter for it. I have very big array so this is taking too much time.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/unique.html

Comment: I think unique will result 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11

Comment: Do you want to count **exactly** two times, or **at least** two times?

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/histc.html):

```
uA = unique(A); %// find unique values
B = uA(histc(A, uA)>=2); %// select those that appear at least twice
```

The above code gives the values that appear *at least* twice. If you want values that appear *exactly* twice, replace `>=` by `==`.

Comment: Not sure you really need the `unique`... `histc` with two output arguments would go a long way too...

Comment: @Floris But you need `unique` for the second input of `histc`, don't you? If `A` has very different values (such as `A = [1 2 1 3 1000 1001 3000 3000]`), using `histc(A, min(A):max(A))` would be inefficient